# Declaring JavaScript extended functions in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have this type of Node.js module written in JavaScript:

```
function main(options) {
    return "some string";
}

main.methodName = function () {
    // implementation;
};

main.objectName = {
    // a namespace;
};

main.propertyName = 123;

module.exports = main;
```

What is the proper way of declaring such an interface in TypeScript?

**CLARIFICATION**

I'm asking about how to properly declare such an interface in TypeScript for an existing Node.js module, so it can be used correctly from TypeScript files, not how to re-implement such interfaces in TypeScript.

**UPDATE**

Following suggestion from @toskv, I have added the following interface:

```
declare module "my-module" {

    // Default library interface
    interface main {
        (options?:{}):string,
        methodName():any,
        propertyName:any,
        objectName:Object
    }

    export default main;
}
```

But if I use it like this:

```
import * as myModule from "my-module";
var s = myModule({});
```

Then I'm getting error `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.`.

Any idea why?

Comment: TypeScript is a superset of JavaScript, which means this code, which is valid JavaScript, is also valid TypeScript.

Comment: @Gothdo while that is true, TypeScript makes it a pain to extend objects after their types are defined because of the static typing. Like adding properties to a function. It's much easier and cleaner to transform the code to a class. :)

Answer (score 3):

A TypeScript interface describing that code would be:

```js
interface MainIf {
    (options) : string ; // the main function
    methodName() : any;
    propertyName: number;
    objectName: Object;
}
```

Comment: indeed he doesn't, but it is cleaner this way. :) the alternative is to add type assertions to <any> when adding the extra properties on the main function. I'll make an example of that too. :)

Comment: I think there maybe some misunderstanding. I was asking for a declaration interface for an existing Node.js module, not for a way to implement a new class that works in the same way.

Comment: @vitaly-t I added another example that just patches the current code to have it work in the typescript compiler. The generated js code for the 2 should be equivalent.

Comment: @vitaly-t I did, does that fit?

Comment: @toskv in my module `main(options)` is a function that returns a string, it is not in any way a class. How to amend it then?

Comment: @vitaly-t that should do it.

Comment: @toskv could you, please look at my updated post and tell me what else am I missing there?

Comment: @toskv I have updated the error to `Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature.`. Any idea what am I missing there?

Comment: where are you getting the error? is it when you call myModule?